# AFNetworking support for iOS4.3 to iOS 7

Tags: ios

I have to replace NSURLConnection with AFNetworking in my iOS application supporting iOS 4.3 to iOS 7. How to support all these versions using Single library file. When AFNetworking2.0 is used it's not supporting iOS 6 Below verssions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide) :

> AFNetworking 2.0 officially supports iOS 6+, Mac OS X 10.8+, and Xcode 5. If you'd like to use AFNetworking in a project targeting a base SDK of iOS 5, or Mac OS X 10.7, use the latest tagged 1.x release. For iOS 4.3 and Mac OS X 10.6 support, use the latest tagged 0.10.x release.

Comment: Keep in mind the 0.10.x release hasn't been updated in almost 2 years.  It may be worth having 2 copies of AFNetworking - 1.x for iOS 6+, and 0.10 for iOS 5-.

Comment: But the issue is my deployment target is 4.3 so when the deployment target is 4.3 it's throwing.